# Passing a List Object from render to Action Phase in Liferay

Tags: object, liferay-6

In my view.jsp there is a List Object which needs to be taken to the Action.java
I am able to pass Lists from Action to Render Phase but not able to do the opposite. 
Please help.

The List Object gets created as a form submission in the view.jsp page. 
I am using MVC Portlet and Liferay portal 6.0.6

Comment: You can pass parameters in form input parameters. Can you provide more information

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible because the order of calling methods is `processAction(...)` and then `render(...)`.

read more about porlet lifecycle:
http://jsr286tutorial.blogspot.de/p/portlet-lifecycle.html

But if the required list is created on the frontend site (browser), you can read the data from the form already in `processAction(...)`

Comment: Hi Mark, Thank you for the response. I get your point. Following your solution, I would have to read all the form entries from the Action Phase, doing so I would have to redo the entire code. Is it anyway possible to pass the List object as Attribute to the Action Phase. I know it works the other way around.